# C - Memory access with mmap

Tags: c, linux, memory, embedded-linux, mmap

I have a hex file of 327680 characters which I'm writing to physical address 0x30000000 - 0x3004FFFF on the memory on my ARM linux system.

While reading back from the memory I'm getting a segfault after reading 64170 characters from the start address, ie at 0x3000FAAA. 
If I change my starting address to 0x3000FA64, then also I get a segfault after 64170 characters.

How do I ensure data is accessed correctly if Data > 4kB (page size) ?

I'm unable to understand the exact problem, so I'm adding the snippet of my code below:

```
#define MAX_RANGE 327679

int fd;
FILE* fd_table=NULL;
unsigned long int count = 0 ;
void * mem;
void * aligned_vaddr;
unsigned long aligned_paddr;
uint32_t aligned_size;
unsigned long int addr_phys;

uint8_t *addr;
int g_size = 1;
unsigned long int g_paddr = 0x30000000; //Starting physical address

while((count<MAX_RANGE)){
  g_paddr = addr_phys;
  g_paddr &= ~(g_size - 1);

  aligned_paddr = g_paddr & ~(4096 - 1);
  aligned_size = g_paddr - aligned_paddr + (g_count * g_size);
  aligned_size = (aligned_size + 4096 - 1) & ~(4096 - 1);

  /* Align address to access size */
  aligned_vaddr = mmap(NULL, aligned_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, aligned_paddr);
  if (aligned_vaddr == NULL) {
    printf("Error mapping address\n");
    close(fd);
    return 1;
  }

  mem = (void *)((uint32_t)aligned_vaddr + (g_paddr - aligned_paddr));
  addr = mem;
  fprintf(fd_table, "%02X\n",addr[0]);
  addr_phys +=1; //Increment byte address
  count++;
}
```

Note: 
1. There is no error in the write process, I have verified by viewing the segfault address with memtool.
2. The address 0x30000000 onwards is not used by the system (I have ensured that in the u-boot).

Comment: I was gonna tell you that 327680 / 64170 is exactly 5, which is a hint that shows that your loop is too "fast" but than I realized that you're calling `mmap()` in the loop. That's wrong! `mmap()` the physical memory once and then use it.

Comment: @simurg thnx I think that should work. Right now my data is <4kB (which is the page size) but what if it is larger than 4kB ?

Comment: Also, what's a "hex file"?

Comment: @MooingDuck a text file with all hex values.